# Why doesn't RemoveAllCacheResponses completely clear the disk cache?

Tags: google-maps, caching, ios7, xamarin

I have an application that uses the Google Map Javascript API v3 and a UIWebView to display a map onscreen. While on this map I can use the app to collect multiple points of GPS data to represent a line.

[image]

After collecting 1460-1480 points the app quits unexpectedly (pinch zooming on the map makes the app quit before the 1400+ threshold is reached). It appears to be a memory issue (my app is the blue wedge of the pie chart).

[image]

The map screen does receive multiple memory warnings that are handled in an overridden DidReceiveMemoryWarning method in this screen. There is some prior code that called NSUrlCache.SharedCache.RemoveAllCachedResponses.

```
public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
{

  // BEFORE
  uint diskUsage = NSUrlCache.SharedCache.CurrentDiskUsage;
  uint memUsage = NSUrlCache.SharedCache.CurrentMemoryUsage;
  int points = _currentEntityManager.GeometryPointCount;
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("BEFORE - diskUsage = {0}, memUsage = {1}, points = {2}", diskUsage, memUsage, points));

  NSUrlCache.SharedCache.RemoveAllCachedResponses();

  // AFTER
  diskUsage = NSUrlCache.SharedCache.CurrentDiskUsage;
  memUsage = NSUrlCache.SharedCache.CurrentMemoryUsage;
  points = _currentEntityManager.GeometryPointCount;
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("AFTER - diskUsage = {0}, memUsage = {1}, points = {2}", diskUsage, memUsage, points));

  base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();     
}
```

I added the BEFORE and AFTER sections so I could track cache contents before and after RemoveAllCachedResponses is called.

The shared cache is configured when the application starts (prior to my working on this issue it was not being configured at all).

```
uint cacheSizeMemory = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
uint cacheSizeDisk = 1024 * 1024 * 32;
NSUrlCache sharedCache = new NSUrlCache(cacheSizeMemory, cacheSizeDisk, "");
NSUrlCache.SharedCache = sharedCache;
```

When we're on this screen collection point data and we receive a low memory warning, RemoveAllCachedResponses is called and the Before/After statistics are printed to the console. Here are the numbers for the first low memory warning we receive.

```
BEFORE - diskUsage = 2258864, memUsage = 605032, points = 1174
AFTER - diskUsage = 1531904, memUsage = 0, points = 1174
```

Which is what I would expect to happen - flushing the cache reduces disk and memory usage (though I would expect the the disk usage number to also go to zero).

All subsequent calls to RemoveAllCachedResponses display these statistics (this Before/After is immediately prior to the app crashing).

```
BEFORE - diskUsage = 1531904, memUsage = 0, points = 1471
AFTER - diskUsage = 1531904, memUsage = 0, points = 1471
```

This leads me to believe one of two things - 1. RemoveAllCachedResponses is not working (unlikely) or 2. there's something in the disk cache that can't be removed because it's currently in use, something like the current set of map tiles.

Regarding #2, I'd like to believe this, figuring the reduction in disk usage on the first call represents a set of tiles that were no longer being used because of a pinch zoom in, but no pinch zooming or panning at all was done on this map, i.e. only one set of initial tiles should have been downloaded and cached.

Also, we are loading the Google Map Javascript API file as local HTML so it could be that this file is what's remaining resident in the cache. But the file is only 18,192 bytes which doesn't jib with the 1,531,904 bytes remaining in the disk cache.

I should also mention that the Android version of this app (written with Xamarin.Android) has no such memory issue on its map screen - it is possible to collect 5500+ points without incident).

So why does the disk cache not go to zero when cleared?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused about this too. You can take a look at the question I asked.
[removeAllCachedResponses can not clear sharedURLCache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803720/removeallcachedresponses-can-not-clear-sharedurlcache)
The comrade said "it has some additional overhead in the cache and it's not related to real network data."