# removeAllCachedResponses can not clear sharedURLCache?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I made a button to clear my cache:

```
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]removeAllCachedResponses];
```

after this being done, I check the size of sharedURLCache:

```
NSInteger sizeInteger = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] currentDiskUsage];
float sizeInMB = sizeInteger / (1024.0f * 1024.0f);
```

the sizeInMB is 0.17, sometimes 0.13. Never 0.0. Why the  removeAllCachedResponses doesn't make the sharedURLCache to ZERO ?

ps:   in AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:2 * 1024 * 1024
                                                                    diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024
                                                                        diskPath:nil];

    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done small experiment with NSURLCache. Code and logs below:

```
NSUInteger memorySize = 1024 * 1024 * 64;
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:memorySize diskCapacity:memorySize diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
NSLog(@"cap: %ld", [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] diskCapacity]);

NSInteger sizeInteger = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] currentDiskUsage];
float sizeInMB = sizeInteger / (1024.0f * 1024.0f);
NSLog(@"size: %ld,  %f", (long)sizeInteger, sizeInMB);

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

sizeInteger = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] currentDiskUsage];
sizeInMB = sizeInteger / (1024.0f * 1024.0f);
NSLog(@"size: %ld,  %f", (long)sizeInteger, sizeInMB);

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

sizeInteger = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] currentDiskUsage];
sizeInMB = sizeInteger / (1024.0f * 1024.0f);
NSLog(@"size: %ld,  %f", (long)sizeInteger, sizeInMB);
```

Logs:

```
2015-08-05 11:26:29.901 lagoon[26845:533709] cap: 67108864
2015-08-05 11:26:29.904 lagoon[26845:533709] size: 86016,  0.082031
2015-08-05 11:26:29.907 lagoon[26845:533709] size: 123128,  0.117424
2015-08-05 11:26:29.910 lagoon[26845:533709] size: 123128,  0.117424
```

It's completely new installation of app without any network requests and there is already some space occupied as you can see in logs. So I think it has some additional overhead in the cache and it's not related to real network data.

Comment: Thanks. I took the test too. Both on the device and simulator the sizes are 0.117424.  I think I have to minus these for showing to user.

Answer (score 4):

During pen test (security testing), I have got issue of caching url request/ response by iOS in cache.db.

I tried using

URLCache.shared.removeCachedResponse(for: URLRequest) and 
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()

Both above API doesn't seems to be working just after getting response from API Call

Then got it working by putting following two line of code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate

```
// first remove all url cache from previous versions of app
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()


// As we do not want to cache any request response so
// updated shared instance of url cache with custom url cache where
// memoryCapacity = 0, diskCapacity = 0 and diskPath = nil
URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the cache is a sqlLite database. Clearing the cache can clear the records in the database, but not resize the database down. That's why disk space seems to be unaffected.